# Valor atríbuido a variável dentro do setOnClickListener não está a ser considerado

Tags: java, android

Então estou fazendo um app de teste mais para estudar mesmo, sou iniciante no android não sei muita coisa, estou tentando fazer com que na aplicação quando eu clico em uma imagem que ele entra nesse método :

```
p1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") 
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                posicao =1;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Imagem 1 selecionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }});
```

Estou querendo saber porque quando ele entra dentro desse método, ele não atribui valor para a variável posição, já tentei outras forma declarei outra variável ali e fiz a posição receber oque estava dentro mais nem assim funciona.

Essa são a imagens esse código acima é do primeira imagem, a ação quando clica na imagem e diz que ela foi selecionada..

A variável posição seria a variável que definiria o valor do if lá embaixo, tanto que quando eu declaro por exemplo posicao = 1 , ou seja posição recebe um fora da função ele funciona sem problemas, mais lá dentro do método p1 que é a imagem da esquerda é como se o posicao = 1 nem estivesse digitado ali.

no final da postagem tem meu código completo...

[image: aplicação no celular]

[image: aplicação no celular]

```
public class Fragment_main extends Fragment {

    public Fragment_main() {
    }

    private int posicao=0;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final View Acess = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ImageView p1 = (ImageView)Acess.findViewById(R.id.p1);
        ImageView p2 = (ImageView)Acess.findViewById(R.id.p2);


        p1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                posicao =1;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Imagem 1 selecionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }});

        p2.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Imagem 2 selecionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                posicao =2;

            }});

       // position =1;

        // pegando o valor que recebeu lá ....
                if (posicao==1) {

            Button caso1button = (Button) Acess.findViewById(R.id.bts); // botão

            //ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)acessR.findViewById(R.id.viewimg); // idimg
            //imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.colorpass); // local da img original

            caso1button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.gpx17); // wallpaper

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wallpaper aplicado com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            posicao = 0;

        }else if (posicao==2) {

            Button caso2button = (Button) Acess.findViewById(R.id.bts); // botão

            //ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)acessR.findViewById(R.id.viewimg); // idimg
            //imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.colorpass); // local da img original

            caso2button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.gpx15); // wallpaper

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wallpaper aplicado com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            posicao = 0;
        }

        return Acess;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código que está nos *listener* só é executado quando for clicada uma imagem.
Por isso, quando a execução chegar à linha

```
if (posicao==1)
```

o valor da variável `posicao` é zero.

O que deve fazer é ter o código que usa o WallpaperManager em um método à parte e aí fazer o `setResource()` de acordo com o valor de `posicao`.

Se eu entendi bem o que pretende será qualquer coisa assim:

```
public class Fragment_main extends Fragment {

    public Fragment_main() {
    }

    private int posicao=0;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final View Acess = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ImageView p1 = (ImageView)Acess.findViewById(R.id.p1);
        ImageView p2 = (ImageView)Acess.findViewById(R.id.p2);


        p1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                posicao =1;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Imagem 1 selecionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }});

        p2.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Imagem 2 selecionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                posicao =2;

            }});

        Button caso1button = (Button) Acess.findViewById(R.id.bts); // botão
        caso1button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                changeWallpaper();
            }
        });


        return Acess;
    }
}

private void changeWallpaper(){

    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
    if (posicao==1) {
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.gpx17); // wallpaper

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wallpaper aplicado com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        posicao = 0;

    }else if (posicao==2) {
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.gpx15); // wallpaper

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wallpaper aplicado com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        posicao = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa obrigadão, deu super certo, não imaginava que precisaria fazer só isso.